# Declaring Arrays in Perl6 with Multiple Ranges

Tags: raku

I'm attempting to create an array in Perl6 with two different ranges as I would have in Perl5:

```
my @cols = (3..9, 11..16);
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5>;
p @cols; exit;
```

However, this creates a 2-D array

```
[
    [0] [
            [0] 3,
            [1] 4,
            [2] 5,
            [3] 6,
            [4] 7,
            [5] 8,
            [6] 9
        ],
    [1] [
            [0] 11,
            [1] 12,
            [2] 13,
            [3] 14,
            [4] 15,
            [5] 16
        ]
]
```

when it should be a 1d array, as `(3..9, 11..16)` would have been in Perl5:

```
[
    [0]  3,
    [1]  4,
    [2]  5,
    [3]  6,
    [4]  7,
    [5]  8,
    [6]  9,
    [7]  11,
    [8]  12,
    [9]  13,
    [10] 14,
    [11] 15,
    [12] 16,
    [13] 17,
    [14] 18,
    [15] 19,
    [16] 20
]
```

I can easily get around this, of course, with `append` but how can I get the Perl5 result of `(3..9, 11..16)` in Perl6 in one line only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `..` operator creates a [Range](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range) object and thus you're creating a list with 2 Range's in it. In order to make a list of the values in the Ranges you need to unroll them and flatten them.

Here are two ways:

- Use a [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Slips):

  ```
   my @cols = (|(3..9), |(11..16))
  ```
- or [`flat`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/flat):

  ```
   my @cols = (3..9, 11..16).flat
  ```

Comment: Shorter: `my @cols = flat 3..9, 11..16;`.